# How to write a makefile that builds only the libraries?

Tags: linux, makefile

I have set of libraries that I use for my application development. Whenever I build the application all libraries are rebuilt. Me and my team team feel it is really unnecessarily to build libraries again and again.

How would I make a makefile which will build all libraries and application independently?
 I mean to say, When I build my app I want to avoid building all libraries that are already built.

Suggest some opinions.

Edit:
Description:
my app is called xyz and all source files are present in ./src/xyz directory.
It depends upon libraries like ssh and net-snmp. And both net-snmp and ssh are put in ./lib directory.

Now whenever the app is built all libraries are re-built. Here I do not modify the library packages that are needed for my app.

It takes nearly an hours time to build. at each build libraries are re-built and this is not required.

Now, My Question?
How do I write a makefile that will build libraries and app separately.

Comment: How have you defined your dependencies? The libraries should rebuild only if their source changes.

Comment: The solution is to make the executables depend on the built libraries instead of on their source code. Please post part of your makefile to know what it is doing now.

Comment: @: Have edited my question and explained the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given us nearly enough information to give a detailed answer, but here's the outline:

```
LIBRARIES = ./lib/ssh ./lib/net-snmp

SOURCES = foo bar baz

xyz: $(LIBRARIES) $(SOURCES)
    command-that-rebuilds-app-from-sources-and-libraries

./lib/ssh: things-that-ssh-needs
    command-that-rebuilds-ssh

./lib/net-snmp: things-that-net-snmp-needs
    command-that-rebuilds-net-snmp

XPATH: ./src
```

Comment: Ok, I got little idea. But is there a way to know if library is already built? So that I need not build the libraries each time and I can skip few steps.

Comment: Make takes care of that for you.  If none of the `things-that-ssh-needs` have changed, then `lib/ssh` will not be rebuilt.  You would always be running `make xyz`.